# Mysql Full Text search not working for all fields

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a large table.  I have Full text index on:

name (company name)
Name_dba (company name doing business as)
phy_city (physical city)
phy_state (physical state)
mail_city
mail_state

I the allow users to simply enter in a company name, city, etc to search.  My code takes the term sing $term and removes any whitespace between the words and replaces it with a "+".  I then do the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM fmcsa_census1
 WHERE MATCH(dot_num, name, name_dba, iccdocket1, icc1,phy_st, phy_city, mail_city, mail_st) AGAINST (('$term') IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This works fine when searching city, state but never matches correctly on company name.  Even when I type in a company name exactly like one I have in the db it isn't returned or returned way down in the results.  Both of the name fields are varchar(120).

Any suggestions as people most likely will be searching by name.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried in the mysql console or only in php?

Comment: Are you sure replacing whitespace with a + isn't the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the way you are forging this$term variable. Maybe you are putting a fot before the city name.